# Append nanosecond to millisecond Python datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to append nanoseconds to an already existing millisecond datetime pandas object. So, for instance, I already have `08:02:36.715647` which reports uptil milliseconds (under column time_m). I then have a separate column titled "nano" that contains the nano part of the datetime (for instance, `976`). How can I append this nanosecond part, so that the datetime reads as `08:02:36.715647976`.

Thanks

Comment: `.715647` - that's *micro*second (1/10^6 s) precision, not *milli*second (1/10^3 s).

Answer (score 0):

you could add as a [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html); EX:

```py
import pandas as pd

ns = 976

t = "08:02:36.715647"

print(pd.to_datetime(t) + pd.to_timedelta(ns, unit='ns'))
2022-04-29 08:02:36.715647976
```